# Sequences of ASCII characters available for use as operators in macros

Tags: julia

The [RecipesBase.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/RecipesBase.jl) `@recipe` macro makes use of a couple special operators constructed out of ASCII characters, namely `-->` and `:=`. These character sequences seem to have some special attribute that allows them to be parsed into an `Expr`. Compare `-->` to `--`:

```
julia> 1 --> 2
ERROR: syntax: invalid syntax 1 --> 2

julia> 1 -- 2
ERROR: syntax: invalid operator "--"

julia> :(1 --> 2)
:($(Expr(:-->, 1, 2)))

julia> :(1 -- 2)
ERROR: syntax: invalid operator "--"
```

Interestingly, `1 --> 2` is parsed with an expression head of `:-->`, whereas other binary operators, including Unicode binary operators such as `↑` (typed as `\uparrow` + `TAB`), are parsed with an expression head of `:call`:

```
julia> dump(:(1 --> 2))
Expr
  head: Symbol -->
  args: Array{Any}((2,))
    1: Int64 1
    2: Int64 2

julia> dump(:(1 ↑ 2))
Expr
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array{Any}((3,))
    1: Symbol ↑
    2: Int64 1
    3: Int64 2
```

So, I have a few related questions:

1. What's up with `-->` and `:=`? (EDIT: In other words, why are those character sequences specially parsed?)
2. Are there other sequences of ASCII characters that behave similarly to `-->` and `:=` and that can therefore be used as operators in macros?
3. Is there documentation somewhere that lists the various "special" sequences of ASCII characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-->` and `:=` are specially parsed by the Julia parser.

Take a look at this file:
https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/f54cdf45a9e04f1450ba22142ddac8234389fe05/src/julia-parser.scm

It lists all of the specially parsed character sequences, and I'm pretty sure you can also get the associativity from it.

Comment: This is helpful, but I would like more explanation before I accept this as the answer. For example... Why are `-->` and `:=` specially parsed? Where exactly in that file does one look for specially parsed character sequences? At one point in that file, the `--` character sequence appears directly adjacent to `-->`. However, I can use `-->` in an `Expr`, but not `--`.

Comment: @CameronBieganek `-->` is different from `↑` in that it is "syntactic-operators", as defined at [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/f54cdf45a9e04f1450ba22142ddac8234389fe05/src/julia-parser.scm#L115). To list all syntactic operators, you can enter the interpreter by running `julia --lisp`, then type "syntactic-operators" and press Enter.

Comment: And about way they are special. I'm not the developer, but I think these operators has special meanings that cannot be expressed by _functions_. Most of the syntactic operators involves assignments, lambda definitions and logical comparison (short circuit cannot be expressed by function). Maybe they thought `-->` might be used for a kind of assignments or lambda definitions.

Comment: @张实唯 That's neat. I didn't know about the `--lisp` option.